# manipulate string to extract date-time

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have `MeasureDateTime` (`nvarchar(50)`) column in my SQL Server table.

I need to get

```
  |measureFilePath   |    MeasureDateTime     |       MeasureName       |
  |  12Nc121         |Thu Jun 19 15:00:05 2011| Annulus 4th RMS (Waves) |
  |  12NB121         |Thu Jul 19 15:38:05 2012| 3.0mm 4th RMS (Waves)   |
  |  12NXc121        |Tue May 15 12:13:02 2012| BC (mm)                 |
  |  12NA121         |Tue May 15 12:13:02 2012| CT (mm)                 |
  |  12Nc111         |Tue May 15 12:13:02 2012| Reference Angle (deg.)  |
  |  12Nc231         |Wed May 15 12:03:02 2013| Temperature (C)         |
```

I want to get last 6 months of data using the `MeasureDateTime` column, for example.

But the problem is `MeasureDateTime` is of `nvarchar` type.

Anyone know how to do this? Is it even possible?

Comment: Why do you store a datetime as string at all?

Comment: If you have control over the table, and can ALTER TABLE, you should consider changing this column to a datetime.

Comment: My guess it is coming like this from some import source and not in a standard date format that SQL understand - hence varchar storage

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries) - you should **not** store dates as strings - you're just asking for trouble that way. Use the `DATE` or `DATETIME` datatypes!

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
CONVERT(datetime,SUBSTRING(MeasureDateTime,4,100),101)
```

to convert the varchar column into a `datetime` format.

`SUBSTRING(MeasureDateTime,4,100)` removes the weekday part of the date string and the `CONVERT()` call with format `101` will accept the US-type date format.

The select could look like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATEADD(month, 6, CONVERT(datetime,SUBSTRING(MeasureDateTime,4,100),101)) > getdate()
```

I ignored the inserted time information before. Here another attempt on the date conversion:

```
convert(datetime,substring(stuff(dt,11,0,right(dt,5)),4,21),101)
```

This approach relies on equal string lengths. I don't know for certain whether that is a given here.

Comment: It doesn't work, but a good thinking... Im gonna work on it soem more... Error msg: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit convoluted but may work:

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(Month, CAST(RIGHT(MeasureDateTime, LEN(MeasureDateTime) - 4) as datetime), GETDATE()) <= 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a trigger for this table when inserting. Try the solution provided by @cars10 to get the date and store it in a `datetime` field. Always keep datetime fields as `datetime` rather than `varchar` fields. Later on you my have to retrieve records based on date and this `datetime` field will prove to be useful.